# How to convert DECIMAL STRING to nearest integer in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, type-conversion

How do I convert a string containing a decimal number to nearest integer value?

For example:

```
string x = "4.72";
```

I want to get 5 as integer.

Comment: That's not a string.. it's a double?

Comment: Your code example would not compile.  First thing you need to do is get it to compile.  Then you want to convert a double/decimal string to an actual `double` or `decimal`.  Then you can use the rounding utilities to _round_ to nearest integer

Comment: Math.Round or (232.423d).ToString("#,##0")

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(Math.Ceiling(Convert.ToDecimal(x)));`

Comment: @EhsanSajjad that would always round it _up_.  OP asked for it to be rounded to the _nearest_ integer.

Comment: then `Round` method to be used

Comment: What's the integer nearest to 4.5, according to your needs? What about -4.5?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: Don't post answers as a comment.

Comment: One note on the marked duplicate, the only difference is that you have to parse the string to a decimal first which is 1 extra (trivial) step. The answer spells out exactly how rounding works.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear that either you want to round or get the ceiling value but we have `Math` class which provides the basic methods to extract the floor value using `Floor()` method or ceiling value using `Ceiling()` or rounded value using the `Round()` like:

```
string x = "4.72";
Console.WriteLine(Math.Ceiling(Convert.ToDecimal(x)));
Console.WriteLine(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDecimal(x)));
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(x)));
```

### Output:

> 5
>
> 4
>
> 5

Please see [this working DEMO Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sY5RCa).

**Note:** for cases where we want the math convention for rounding the decimal points then we should always be calling the `Math.Round()`.

Comment: right. ceiling will always move the number to the next, but round would change 4.5 to 4. 

depending on the required logic math.round might be enough, but if you require for 4.5 to move to 5, then you need Ceiling

Comment: It's probably safe to say you want to use the 3rd line.  Math.Round uses the most commonly held practice of rounding .5 up.  ex. 1.5 = 2.

Comment: It gets 5 as decimal i want to assign it a int variable. 
Lİke:
string x = "4.72"; 
int y= (int)Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(x));
But i get 472 as result.

Comment: You will need to convert it to integer back

Comment: @Mike there is also an overload with a MidpointRounding parameter. `MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero` would round 4.5 to 5.

Comment: @Furkan you are working in a culture where the decimal is a comma (and the `.` is just a grouping separator). Specify `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` in the Convert

Comment: @HansKeﬆing yes i replaced point with comma and it solved my problem. Thank you sir.